# How to count all the solutions for $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{k_i}}= 1$ for $k_i\in \Bbb{N}$ and $n$ a fixed positive integer?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions, inclusion-exclusion

After reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136618/how-to-find-all-the-solutions-for-sum-limits-i-1n-frac12k-i-1-f), I would like to just count all solutions for:

$$\frac{1}{2^{k_1}} + \frac{1}{2^{k_2}} + \frac{1}{2^{k_3}} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^{k_n}}=1$$

for $k_i\in \Bbb{N}$ (we can include $0$) with $n$ a fixed positive integer.

I noticed that if we denote with $f(k)$ the number of times the value $k$ appears in the sequence $k_i$ then:

$$2^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2^{n-k}f(k)}$$

and also

$$n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{f(k)}$$

So the problem is equivalent to count all $f(0), ... ,f(n)$ solutions to the system of the last two equations.

I tried to apply the star and bars method and inclusion-exclusion principle, but with no success so far.

**EDIT 2019-08-14**

After reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1694313/573047) to another question, I found that the number of solutions is the coefficient of $x^ny^{2^n}$ of the generating function:

$$\frac{1}{(1-xy)(1-xy^2)(1-xy^4)\ldots(1-xy^{2^{n-1}})(1-xy^{2^n})}$$

but is it possible to get a formula?

Answer (score 2):

Using the solution scheme by Crostul in the mentioned foregoing [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136618/how-to-find-all-the-solutions-for-sum-limits-i-1n-frac12k-i-1-f) I let Mathematica compute the number $a(n)$ of solutions $k_1\leq k_2\leq\ldots\leq k_n$ for $1\leq n\leq11$ and obtained the sequence
$$1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 16, 28, 50, 89, \dots\quad.$$
This is sequence [A002572](http://oeis.org/A002572) at OEIS, where reference is made to this problem, and additional information is given.

Comment: So there is no hope for a formula, right?

Comment: At A002572 there is no formula; but I would not use the words "no hope".