# When is the sum of the inverses of a finite, nondecreasing sequence of nonnegative numbers $1$?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, algorithms

This question is a simple generalization of a math problem I saw somewhere.

Consider the family of sets
$$
A_n \equiv \{(a_1, \ldots, a_n)\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}^n \, : \,  a_1 \leq \cdots \leq a_n \text{ and }  \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{a_k} = 1\}
$$

I think there are many interesting questions that could be asked about these $A_n$. Here are the ones I'm curious about:

1. Is there a paper or standard reference on these $A_n$ I should know about?
2. How fast does $|A_n |$ grow?
3. What's the best way to calculate the elements of $A_n$?

If Math SE etiquette requires pinning me down to one question, I'm most interested in reading about this problem elsewhere, assuming it has already been written about (which I'm sure is a safe assumption).

---

So far, I've come up with an algorithm for calculating the $A_n$. Suppose $a_1, \ldots, a_k$ are given with $k < n$. Then
$$
\sum_{j = k + 1}^n \frac{1}{a_j} = 1 - \sum_{j = 1}^k \frac{1}{a_j} > 0
$$
(If the RHS is $\leq 0$, there is no choice of $a_{k + 1}$ that works, and we are done).

But
$$
\sum_{j = k + 1}^n \frac{1}{a_j} \leq \frac{n- k}{a_{k + 1}}
$$
since $1 \leq a_1 \leq \cdots \leq a_n$. Thus
$$
\frac{n-k}{a_{k + 1}} \geq 1 - \sum_{j = 1}^k \frac{1}{a_j}
$$
Therefore
$$
a_{k + 1} \leq \frac{n - k}{1 - \sum_{j = 1}^k \frac{1}{a_j}}
$$
That is
$$
a_{k+1} \in \left\{n \in \mathbb{Z} : a_k \leq n \leq \left\lfloor \frac{n - k}{1 - \sum_{j = 1}^k \frac{1}{a_j}}\right\rfloor\right\} \equiv B_{k + 1}
$$
where $B_{k + 1}$ is clearly finite (and depends on $a_1, \ldots, a_k$). We may then pick a value for $a_{k +1}$ from $B_{k + 1}$ and similarly constrain the values for $a_{k + 2}$. We continue in this way until we get $B_j = \emptyset$ for some $j$ or until we've checked every element of $B_n$. We then select a different value for $a_{k + 1}$ from $B_{k + 1}$ and repeat. Once we've exhausted all the possibilities in $B_{k + 1}$, we make a different choice for $a_k$ from $B_k$ and so on until we've checked every possibility. Note that we always have $a_1 \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, so there are definitely only finitely many possibilities to check.

Computer science is not my specialty. I'm sure there's a more elegant and rigorous way to describe this algorithm, but hopefully you get the idea. In particular, I hope it's clear that $A_n$ is finite and can be calculated by performing a finite (though possibly very large per this algorithm) number of computations.

If you're curious, the first few $A_n$ are:
\begin{align}
A_1 &= \{(1)\}
\\A_2 &= \{(2,2)\}
\\A_3 &= \{(2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 4), (3,3,3)\}
\end{align}

Comment: The term you want to look up is "Egyptian fraction": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction

Comment: This problem I found on that page has a lot of similar elements: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Graham_problem

Comment: Regarding question 2 see [OEIS A002966](http://oeis.org/A002966). There are a lot of sequences in OEIS related to Egyptian fractions along with references to papers discussing algorithms to compute decompositions.

Comment: Regarding the particular case where the $a_i$ are powers of $2$, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3138634/573047

Comment: @BillyJoe Well there it is. Thank you. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding question $2$ see [OEIS A002966](https://oeis.org/A002966). There are a lot of sequences at OEIS related to Egyptian fractions along with references to papers discussing algorithms to compute decompositions.

In case you are interested on the particular case where the $a_i$ are powers of $2$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138634/how-to-count-all-the-solutions-for-sum-limits-i-1n-frac12k-i-1) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3136618/how-to-find-all-the-solutions-for-sum-limits-i-1n-frac12k-i-1-f).